# Prevent cursor movement when clicking "../" in netrw

Tags: netrw

When using `netrw` or the *native* vim file explorer, every time I click on `../`, the cursor moves to the top of the page. This is very irritating when I'm trying to go up multiple directories - I have to scroll back down to the `../` and click again, only to have my cursor sent to the top of the buffer yet again.

Is there some way to prevent this?

I'm using Vim 7.4, with the following `netrw` specific setting:

```
let g:netrw_liststyle=3
```

Comment: I don't see this problem. I used: `gvim /home/martin`, and then tried both selecting `../` with the keyboard (Enter) and clicking on it with the mouse. I go up a directory, and in this new directory `../` is selected again. Perhaps the problem is something in your vimrc file? Try [How do I debug my vimrc file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51).

Comment: That is intersting.. it even happens with `vim -U NONE`

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that I've enabled the file tree setting.. see the edited question

Comment: I can reproduce the problem when setting `let g:netrw_liststyle=3` ;-) By the way: `vim -U NONE` prevents loading the gvimrc file, *not* the vimrc file. You need to use `vim -u NONE` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in netrw. I looked at the code and tried to fix it, but after a few minutes I gave up. The code is not exactly readable...

I did notice that pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> while on the first line makes the cursor jump to the `../` line; so pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice works, this may be an acceptable work-around for you.

If not, I suggest contacting the netrw author as listed in [`:help pi_netrw.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html)

PS.
I discovered what seems to be another bug, if I start Vim with `vim /home/martin`, then press <kbd>jj<Enter</kbd> to open the first directory, and go back up to `../`, I need to select it *twice* before I go to the root directory.